# R Timestamp from character to date calculate in seconds

Tags: r

I have a lot of records loaded as strings and I need to convert them to dates and then calculate the difference in time. The conversion below is only giving me a short date. I need the time stamp included and also how do I calculate the difference into an output totaling seconds.

Example below is a difference of 2 minutes so I would like to see an output of 120.

```
as.Date("Apr 17 2013  4:30:00:000PM", "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")
as.Date("Apr 17 2013  4:32:00:000PM", "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: -1 `?Date` tells you "Dates are represented as the number of days since 1970-01-01" and it doesn't mention times anywhere. The "See Also" section points you to "'DateTimeClasses' for date-time classes", which would have answered your question.

Comment: Might have worked with `as.POSIXct` but `as.Date` seemed doomed from the very start.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong type -- use eg `strptime()` inside of `difftime()`:

```
R> difftime(strptime("Apr 17 2013 4:30:00:000PM", "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S"), 
+           strptime("Apr 17 2013 4:32:00:000PM", "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S"))
Time difference of -2 mins
R> difftime(strptime("Apr 17 2013 4:30:00:000PM", "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S"), 
+           strptime("Apr 17 2013 4:32:00:000PM", "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S"), 
+           unit="secs")
Time difference of -120 secs
R>
```

Reordering gives you positive differences.  `as.numeric()` gives you numbers. Searching help here for either of the commands will give you *plenty* of other examples.

Comment: tsk, tsk. You're encouraging bad behavior.

Comment: And you need `"%I"` with AM/PM, not `"%H"`. This is also in the documentation. :p